# Capistrano Create a Deploy User on Local Windows Machine

Tags: linux, capistrano

I'm trying to setup a Git deployment system from my local Windows machine to 3 linux servers using [WP-Stack](https://github.com/markjaquith/WP-Stack). WP-Stack is essentially Capistrano, and in order to setup deployments, I need to create a 'deploy' user and get it on each of the linux servers. I don't do a lot of server/bash work, so this is really confusing to me. How do I create the deploy user on my local Windows machine and then push it to my servers?

Answer (score 0):

Your local machine does not need a deploy user.